# Google Sign-In is redirecting to google chrome not returning to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with Google Sign-in not redirecting back to my app.

I have [followed the steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), installed cocoapods, downloaded the GoogleService-Info.plist (added it to all of my targets), added the URL Types (my bundle identifier and then my reverse client ID to my target and followed the steps line by line.

Added all the url scheme in LSApplicationQueriesSchemes as suggested in other thread [Google Sign-In is not returning to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32769369/google-sign-in-is-not-returning-to-my-app)

On clicking google sign in button it opens safari web view and on clicking "allow" button it redirects to google chrome home page in place of redirecting to my app.

I think that's why didn't get callback in open url.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there must be an issue with your other pods installed say `Branch / Localytics` which performs `method swizzling` internally and does not call `OpenURL` of `AppDelegate.m`. (This was the issue in my case)

If you make a separate test project and perform the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating) everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank. Yes third party libraries creating issues in my code. After commenting out that its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the AppDelegate, Add below methods.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, 
sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool
{
    let googleDidHandle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handleURL(url,
        sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
        annotation: annotation)
    return googleDidHandle
}
```

Google sends back this information through URL. This above method get this information and send back to the Application.

Comment: I am working in objective c and already added these functions (both for ios 8 and below) but problem is didn't get the call in these functions.
When I allow the permission in webview it redirects to google chrome and on clicking "Done", call received at didSignInForUser (delegate method) with user nil.

Comment: you can call [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signInSilently]; to repopulate the signin values after the user has signed in before.

Comment: But problem is callback not received from google signIn. canOpenUrl is returning YES for added urlType scheme in info.plist but call not received at openURL.